# Correctly formatting data

Tags: python

i have a list of strings i read from  a file, i currently convert them all to integers and then strip them from the list, i am doing this as shown below

```
def reading_ppm(file_name):

    f = open (file_name)
    setting = f.readline().splitlines()
    comment = f.readline().splitlines()
    size_x, size_y = f.readline().split()
    pixel_max = f.readline().splitlines()
    orig_data = f.read().split()        

    return size_x,size_y,pixel_max, orig_data

data = map(int, orig_data)
data =  str(data).strip('[]')
```

when i write data to a new file i get:

```
255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
```

however what i want to get is

```
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
```

how can i quickly turn my long string, into ints that appear on a new line rather than all in one ?

Thanks

here is me writing the file

```
def writting_ppm(ppm_file,size_x,size_y,maxval,data):
    colour = 'P3'
    print size_x
    print size_y
    # maxval =  str(maxval).strip('['']')
    maxval = 255
    # data =  str(data).strip('[]')
    # print data
    with open(ppm_file, "w") as text_file:
        text_file.write(colour + "\n" + "\n" +str(size_x) + " " + str(size_y) + "\n" + str(maxval) +"\n" + (data) )
```

i am trying to implement a loop to do this :

```
with open(ppm_file, "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(colour + "\n" + "\n" +str(size_x) + " " + str(size_y) + "\n" + str(maxval) +"\n")
    count = 0
    while count < len(data):
        text_file.write(data[count] + "\n")
        count = count + 1
```

but am currently getting errors, is the the right way to do this ?

Comment: can you show the code where you write to a file?

Comment: Why are you calling `str()` on a list and then stripping the `[]`? Just write a loop.

Comment: Added the code torwite to a file above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `for` loop and don't hack to strip the `[]`. something like this:

```
def writting_ppm(ppm_file,size_x,size_y,maxval,data):
    colour = 'P3'
    print size_x
    print size_y
    # leave data as a list
    maxval =  max(maxval) # use max to get the max int in a list
    with open(ppm_file, "w") as text_file:
        text_file.write(colour + "\n" + "\n" +str(size_x) + " " + str(size_y) + "\n" + str(maxval) +"\n")
        for each in data:
            text_file.write(str(each)+'\n')
```